# How to buffer data read from a large file without newlines

Tags: c, buffer, stdio

I am reading from a file with several thousand floats written in plain text in it, in sections that are separated by newlines.  The floats themselves are separated by whitespace, and occasionally a semi-colon (to separate every group of 3).  A newline character doesn't appear until at the very end, an unknown (but probably tens of thousands) of characters later.

The language I'm using is C

```
3Dmodel.txt
-----

Obj1 Vertice count=5842;
{
0.499507 -0.003674 0.699311; 0.454010 -0.075165 ... -0.022236 \n (newline)
}
```

My question is, what is the best way to extract the strings from the file and into memory?

I cannot use `fgets()` it seems, because the newline is so far out, and because it may end reading in the middle of a float, leaving it incomplete.  Reading the entire file into memory seems needlessly expensive, though it wouldn't be terrible if it were the only way, as each file is only 2MB to 10MB large.

Comment: Have you tried `fscanf`?

Comment: I won't lie, C++ parsing is a bit easier than C. But fscanf for floats works well.

Comment: @larsmans - ... I am so dense.  I use `scanf()` all the time, and yet.  Having a Duh Moment today.  Thank you!

Comment: You don't need a newline to work with `fgets`, _The fgets() function shall read bytes from stream into the array pointed to by s, **until n-1 bytes are read**, or a <newline> is read and transferred to s, or an end-of-file condition is encountered._

Comment: @AlterMann: the problem is if n-1 bytes happens to land in the middle of one of the floats...

Comment: @ChrisDodd, take a look to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it may end reading in the middle of a float ...

Thats not a problem for `fgets`, if a float is cutted, `fseek` to the begin of such float and continue reading from there, example:

/* data */

```
1.23 2.12 3.24 98.88 78.243 3.34 3.4 23.5 54.5
7.8 9.0
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s[16], *p, *q;
    double d;
    FILE *f;

    f = fopen("data", "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while ((p = fgets(s, sizeof s, f)) != NULL) {
        while (1) {
            d = strtod(p, &q);
            if (p == q) break;
            if (*q == '\0') {
                /* cutted, must adjust */
                printf("Cutted at <%s>, adjusting ...\n", p);
                fseek(f, -strlen(p), SEEK_CUR);
                break;
            }
            printf("%f\n", d);
            p = q;
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1.230000
2.120000
3.240000
98.880000
78.243000
Cutted at < 3.>, adjusting ...
3.340000
3.400000
23.500000
54.500000
7.800000
9.000000
```

Comment: Why bother with all the extra work?  Your double-while-loop can be replaced with `while (fscanf("%lf", &d)==1) { printf("%f\n", d); }`.

Comment: Thats true in this case, but in general `fscanf` must be avoided (disk access is expensive)

Comment: I ended up using `fscanf`, querying for 9 floats per call since the number of floats was guaranteed to be divisible by 9.  But for other cases, this is a very efficient solution I think.